# How to change the default icon of my program in C?

Tags: c, windows, icons, dev-c++

i wrote a program in C using Dev-Cpp, my question is : how can i change and customize this program icon ?

Comment: A program don't always have an icon (it is operating system specific).

Comment: You can try a resource hacker like [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm)

Comment: some of the Resource editors not working for my case, mostly they appear an error saying : No resources found in this program.     since it's just a DOS based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program will default to the lowest-numbered icon in its resources. (If you don't have a resource script yet then you need to add one to your project.)

Comment: Yes i got it, i used both Resource Hacker and Resource Tuner to do it! thank you all.